# How can I stop Mission Control rearranging windows when I drag a window and press CTRL+number?

Tags: keyboard, macos, mission-control

I have a setup with 4 Desktops/Spaces. When I click <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> the focus moves to that desktop. When I want to move an app from desktop 1 to 3 I drag the window a bit and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> (or 2 or 4 — these are Spaces/Desktop numbers). For some reason, the apps in other desktops move randomly from their desktops (rearranging the whole layout by moving other apps between desktops). Am I doing something wrong or is this some kind of bug?

I’m on Mavericks 10.9.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to System Preferences → Mission Control and make sure that the checkbox for **Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use** is **disabled**.

[image]

I am able to reproduce your scenario perfectly with this checkbox enabled and disabling this checkbox causes the spaces to be fixed in their position regardless of the switching of window position.